# How to iterate over a 300 pages with a parser with Perl::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, parsing, mechanize

I have written a little parser that extracts the data out of a page.

```
use strict; 
use warnings FATAL => qw#all#; 
use LWP::UserAgent; 
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath; 
use Data::Dumper; 

my $handler_relurl      = sub { q#https://europa.eu# . $_[0] }; 
my $handler_trim        = sub { $_[0] =~ s#^\s*(.+?)\s*$#$1#r }; 
my $handler_val         = sub { $_[0] =~ s#^[^:]+:\s*##r }; 
my $handler_split       = sub { [ split $_[0], $_[1] ] }; 
my $handler_split_colon = sub { $handler_split->( qr#; #, $_[0] ) }; 
my $handler_split_comma = sub { $handler_split->( qr#, #, $_[0] ) }; 

my $conf = 
{ 
    url      => q#https://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/evs-organisation_en#, 
    parent   => q#//div[@class="vp ey_block block-is-flex"]#, 
    children => 
    { 
        internal_url => [ q#//a/@href#, [ $handler_relurl ] ], 
        external_url => [ q#//i[@class="fa fa-external-link fa-lg"]/parent::p//a/@href#, [ $handler_trim ] ], 
        title        => [ q#//h4# ], 
        topics       => [ q#//div[@class="org_cord"]#, [ $handler_val, $handler_split_colon ] ], 
        location     => [ q#//i[@class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-lg"]/parent::p#, [ $handler_trim ] ], 
        hand         => [ q#//i[@class="fa fa-hand-o-right fa-lg"]/parent::p#, [ $handler_trim, $handler_split_comma ] ], 
        pic_number   => [ q#//p[contains(.,'PIC no')]#, [ $handler_val ] ], 
    } 
}; 

print Dumper browse( $conf ); 

sub browse 
{ 
    my $conf = shift; 

    my $ref = [ ]; 

    my $lwp_useragent = LWP::UserAgent->new( agent => q#IE 6#, timeout => 10 ); 
    my $response = $lwp_useragent->get( $conf->{url} ); 
    die $response->status_line unless $response->is_success; 
    my $content = $response->decoded_content; 

    my $html_treebuilder_xpath = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( $content ); 
    my @nodes = $html_treebuilder_xpath->findnodes( $conf->{parent} ); 
    for my $node ( @nodes ) 
    { 
        push @$ref, { };  

        while ( my ( $key, $val ) = each %{$conf->{children}} ) 
        { 
            my $xpath    = $val->[0]; 
            my $handlers = $val->[1] // [ ]; 

            $val = ($node->findvalues( qq#.$xpath# ))[0] // next; 
            $val = $_->( $val ) for @$handlers; 
            $ref->[-1]->{$key} = $val; 
        } 
    } 

    return $ref; 
}
```

on a first glance the issue about scraping from page to page - can be solved via different approaches:

we have the pagination on the bottom of the page: see for example:

```
http://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/evs-organisation_en?country=&topic=&field_eyp_vp_accreditation_type=All&town=&name=&pic=&eiref=&inclusion_topic=&field_eyp_vp_feweropp_additional_mentoring_1=&field_eyp_vp_feweropp_additional_physical_environment_1=&field_eyp_vp_feweropp_additional_other_support_1=&field_eyp_vp_feweropp_other_support_text=&&page=5
```

and

```
http://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/evs-organisation_en?country=&topic=&field_eyp_vp_accreditation_type=All&town=&name=&pic=&eiref=&inclusion_topic=&field_eyp_vp_feweropp_additional_mentoring_1=&field_eyp_vp_feweropp_additional_physical_environment_1=&field_eyp_vp_feweropp_additional_other_support_1=&field_eyp_vp_feweropp_other_support_text=&&page=6
```

and

```
http://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/evs-organisation_en?country=&topic=&field_eyp_vp_accreditation_type=All&town=&name=&pic=&eiref=&inclusion_topic=&field_eyp_vp_feweropp_additional_mentoring_1=&field_eyp_vp_feweropp_additional_physical_environment_1=&field_eyp_vp_feweropp_additional_other_support_1=&field_eyp_vp_feweropp_other_support_text=&&page=7
```

well we can set this url (s) as a base -

if we have an array from which we load the urls that need to be visited - we would come across all the pages...

**Note:** we have more than 6000 results - and on each page 21 little entries that represent one record: so we have approx 305 Pages that we have to visit.
we can increment the pages (that are shown above) and count to the number of 305

Hardcoding the total number of pages isn't practical as it could vary. we could:
- extract the number of results from the first page, divide that by the results per page ( 21 ) and round it down.
- extract the url from the "last" link at the bottom of the page, create a URI object and read the page number from the query string.

now i think i have to Loop over all the pages.

```
my $url_pattern = 'https://europa.eu/youth/volunteering/evs-organisation_en&page=%s'; 

for my $page ( 0 .. $last ) 
{ 
    my $url = sprintf $url_pattern, $page; 

    ... 
}
```

or i try to incorporate paging into the $conf, perhaps an iterator which upon each call fetches the next node...

Comment: soooo, what's the question?

Comment: how to loop over the pages - how to do the looping?

Comment: I use the last command ; it is like the break statement in C (as used in loops); it immediately exits the loop in question. If the LABEL is omitted, the command refers to the innermost enclosing loop. The last EXPR  allows a label name to be computed at run time, and is otherwise identical to last LABEL . The continue block, if any, is not executed:
`
        LINE: while (<STDIN>) {
            last LINE if /^$/;  # exit when done with header
            #...
        }` I am tryin to incorporate this into my code. Thanks to Daxim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After parsing each page, check for the existence of the **`next ›`** link at the bottom. When you have arrived on page 292, there are no more pages, so you are done and can exit the loop with e.g. [`last`](http://p3rl.org/last).

Comment: I use the last command ; it is like the break statement in C (as used in loops); it immediately exits the loop in question. If the LABEL is omitted, the command refers to the innermost enclosing loop. The last EXPR allows a label name to be computed at run time, and is otherwise identical to last LABEL . The continue block, if any, is not executed: ` LINE: while (<STDIN>) { last LINE if /^$/; # exit when done with header #... }` I am tryin to incorporate this into my code. Thanks to Daxim